# Pusher add CSRF token to form data

Tags: php, forms, laravel, csrf, pusher

I'm trying to implement private channel authorization with Pusher and Laravel.

The forms require a CSRF input field (randomized input name and value).  Normally I use twig to insert them into the forms I put on the page.

How can I insert the csrf fields into the form data that Pusher sends when it tries to connect to the auth endpoint?  It isn't present in the form data (but is present in the request header), so it's getting rejected by the laravel CSRF middleware.

Comment: Add the key `_token` with its proper value to the pusher form data.

Comment: @Asur yea I'm asking HOW to add to the outgoing form data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel, this isn't necessary, you shouldn't implement your auth endpoint like this. Your auth endpoint should be defined inside channels.php in the routes folder. For example

```
// routes/channels.php

Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
    return Auth::check();
});
```

CSRF not necessary.